# PHPUnit - Mock PDO Statement fetch

Tags: mocking, pdo, phpunit, fetch

Still in the process of testing a mapper class, I need to mock PDO.
But now I ran into an infinite loop problem:

```
$arrResult = array(
                    array('id'=>10, 'name'=>'abc'),
                    array('id'=>11, 'name'=>'def'),
                    array('id'=>12, 'name'=>'ghi')
                    );

$STMTstub->expects($this->any())
            ->method('fetch')
            ->will($this->returnValue($arrResult));
$PDOstub = $this->getMock('mockPDO');
    $PDOstub->expects($this->any())
            ->method('prepare')
            ->will($this->returnValue($STMTstub));
```

Of course, that code is perfect when it come to test 1 fetch or a fetchAll. But when it come to multiple fetch, the infinite loop happen. Like in that case:

```
while($arr = $stmt->fetch()){
    //...
}
```

So I'd like the fetch() to loop through all the $arrResult and return the sub-array one by one to simulate the true fetch() behavior. Can I "hook a function" to do so or something ?

Comment: I think the way to go is with onConsecutiveCall(). ( See: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest6.php )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. For a few results you can use `at()` to order the returned values, or
2. for more results you can use `returnCallback()` to call a function that yields the desired results across multiple calls.

Using `at()` is pretty straight-forward. You pass in an index that PHPUnit matches up against the calls to pick which expectation to fire. Note that the index passed to `at()` is across all calls to the mock. If `$STMTstub` will receive other mocked calls between the calls to `fetch()`, you'll need to adjust the indexes accordingly.

```
$STMTstub->expects($this->at(0))
          ->method('fetch')
          ->will($this->returnValue($arrResult[0]));
$STMTstub->expects($this->at(1))
          ->method('fetch')
          ->will($this->returnValue($arrResult[1]));
$STMTstub->expects($this->at(2))
          ->method('fetch')
          ->will($this->returnValue($arrResult[2]));
```

Using `returnCallback()` will require a bit more scaffolding, but it avoids all the index shenanigans. ;)

```
public static function yieldResults($name, $results) {
    static $indexes = array();
    if (isset($indexes[$name])) {
        $index = $indexes[$name] + 1;
    }
    else {
        $index = 0;
    }
    self::assertLessThan(count($results), $index);
    $indexes[$name] = $index;
    return $results[$index];
}

public function testMyPdo() {
    $STMTmock = ...
    $STMTmock->expects($this->any())->method('fetch')
             ->will($this->returnCallback(function() {
                 return self::yieldResults('testMyPdo', 
                     array(
                         array('id'=>10, 'name'=>'abc'),
                         array('id'=>11, 'name'=>'def'),
                         array('id'=>12, 'name'=>'ghi'),
                     );});
}
```

`yieldResults()` is generic and will work with any number of simultaneous result sets as long as you give each a unique `$name`. If you're not using PHP 5.3 with callbacks, wrap the call to `yieldResults()` inside another function whose name you pass to `returnCallback()`. I haven't tested it out, but it seems fairly sound.

Comment: Wont let me edit because of 6 characters, but the function definition should read "yieldResults" instead of "yieldNthResult"